# How to return the last row number before auto page break?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm working on a sheet containing multiple pages (to print). I have setted pageBreaks to true

```
sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
```

and when I put something (some rows) into a page, I want to know the last row number before the last page break.

I can't do a simple subtraction between total page rows and used rows because I don't know rows height...

```
sheet.getLastRowNum()
```

returns the last row but it's not the last row before page break...

Comment: Auto page breaks are dependent of printer settings. Page size letter vs. A4 for example. So `apache poi` will have problems to calculate the page breaks since it does not kow the printer settings. `Excel` itself will calculate the page breaks according to the settings of the default printer of the system it is running on. But `apache poi` mostly is not running on the system, on which the `Excel` is running on.

Comment: the printer settings is set to A4 paper on the excel template.